# Please some information regarding Java code

Tags: java

My version so far:

```
boolean isEmpty(int[]arr) {

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        if(arr[i] != 0) {
            return false;
}

    return true; 
}
```

I've changed it, but still not working... How should it be written then?

Comment: By no elements do you mean that all elements are `0`, or the array is empty itself? And what do you think the assignment `a=0;` should do?

Comment: "=" is the assignment operator. Use "==" to test for equality. You need to rethink your logic - try working through it with paper and pencil.

Comment: why you have `boolean y` parameter?!!

Comment: You have so many errors in your code: 1) No need for boolean y. 2) You obviously mean arr.length. 3) a=0; Type Mismatch: 0 is not an array. 4) if statement needs "==" to check. 5) Your return is inside the loop. It will check the first element only.

Comment: Use the compiler messages and learn syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = 0` is wrong since `a` is an `int` array. You're probably looking for a counter variable. It could be like this:

```
boolean existsData = false;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    //arr[i] = 0 means assign 0 to arr[i]
    //note that I'm using different (!=)
    existsData = (arr[i] != 0);
    if (existsData) {
        break;
    }
}
return existData;
```

Or even easier, without using a `boolean` variable:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Or, if you really mean no elements in the array, and not "no 0 elements":

```
boolean isEmpty(int[] arr) {
  return arr.length == 0; 
}
```

Comment: I've changed the code to for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
       if (arr[i] != 0) {
          return false;
      }
     }
    return true; but still not working..

Comment: @JohnSmith what do you mean by *it's not working*? Note that we are developers, not end users.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an array of `int`'s, it is not, itself an `int`...

```
int[]a = new[a.length];
```

Is invalid, because `a` has yet to be declared...

```
a=0;
```

Is invalid, because `a` is an array of `int`s not an `int` itself, it's a different type...

```
if(a[i] = 0)
```

Is an assignment, meaning you are assigning the value `0` to the `a[i]` (or nth position in the `a` array)

But, even if the the comparison was correct, it's unlikely that your method would return a valid value...for example...

```
if(a[i] == 0)
    y=true;
else
    y=false;
```

If you had two elements in the array `{1, 0}`, your method would return `true`, but if they had `{0, 1}`, it would return `false`...

As soon as you find a single value that is not `0`, you should `break` out of the loop and return an appropriate response (`false` in this case)

You also don't need `a` at all.  You should be using `arr`, that's the actual array you want to check...

I would also, highly, recommend that you use `{...}` around you blocks...it will make reading your code much simper, for example...

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] = 0) {
        y=true;
    } else {
        y=false;
    }
}
return y;
```

Now it's obvious where the `return` statement would be called ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is these error presents:

Line 2:int[]a = new[a.length];
you cannot use a.length before it's deceleration...I think it is arr.length();

Line3: a=0;
Here a is not a variable ..a is the refference of a array so you cann't set it's value 0...
you can set like a[0]=0;,a[1]=0;
  or you can set it a=null;

Line5: if(a[i] = 0)

in the if loop it requires only boolean value..So make it a[i]==0;